# Movie Clip On Plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

In blender cycles render engine, how do I put a movie clip on a plane so it displays the video? I want the video to be on the plane if there is a way.

Comment: This question was interesting to me for that I was working on that subject lately.  I solved how to play a video  withing an animation using the second solution proposed below.  However I would like to mention that in the latest release of Blender that is at this time 2.78.4 there is no option to import any formats like it is mentioned in the first answer below by @cegaton.  Maybe this is a temporary situation but because this, one has to use a texture on a plane and select movie as type of texture like it is described in the second answer.

Comment: At 2.8 for me its just workd if i imported from the file menu.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the *Import: Images as Planes* addon:

[image: screenshot 1]

or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select *Add -> Mesh -> Images as Planes*.

In Blender 2.9x it's located in *Add -> Images -> Images as Planes*.

[image: screenshot 2]

Select the video file you want to use as texture (and what kind of shader you want)

[image: screenshot 3]

Blender will then create a plane with the dimensions of the video file and will create the materials for the texture.

[image: screenshot 4]

[image: screenshot 5]

Using the default values will make the video playback start on the 1st frame of the blender scene.

You can use the **Frames** control to limit the number of frames of the video you want to use. (for example if your video has 1000 frames but you only want to use 215 you'd set that value here)

The **Start Frame** control will allow you to delay the beginning of the video playback (moving it to 100 for instance will make the video pause for 100 frames and start playing on the scene's frame 101, for example)

The **Offset** control will allow you to choose the starting frame of the video (if your video has 1000 frames and you want to ignore the first 35 frames you would set the offset to 35)

[image: screenshot 6]

Make sure auto-refresh is enabled.

NOTES:

- The texture on the Plane will be visible only when the shading in the 3D viewport is set to *Material preview* or *Rendered*.

[image: screenshot 7]

For older versions use *Texture* or *Rendered*.

[image: screenshot 8]

- The images in rendered mode do not refresh at every frame.

Read: [Image sequence texture: no preview?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105750/image-sequence-texture-no-preview/105753#105753)

Comment: THANK YOU! Finally someone who understands it and was able to explain it!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with an *Image Texture* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Texture > Image Texture*). Once you have an image texture node, change the *Source* option from `Single Image` to `Movie` as shown. Make sure the plane is UV Unwrapped, and that you load your movie file path into the node.

[image]