# How can I use a sequence of images as a texture within a render scene?

Tags: rendering, animation

My scene contains a 'projector screen', and I wish to animate some other items, while changing the image that is shown on the screen. Currently, I'm using a plane with the image(s) used as an image texture. I am then manually rendering each frame individually and changing the image. Obviously this is a huge waste of time, so I was wondering how I could perform this in a more sensible manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Yes. Instead of using an image on the plain, use a series of images using the node setup shown. Add > Image, and then select your image series.

You can also texture a plane with a movie file. [Movie Clip On Plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane)

Whichever way you go, frame rates must match...

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I figured there must be a simple solution!

Comment: I had to wait for a certain time period apparently, apologies for the delay!