# Multiple video segments in multiple textures

Tags: scripting

Animating video plane movements for EEVEE in Blender 2.80 that pass through the field of view of the camera in combinations: The h.264 video file is long. To start each plane on a different frame before it enters the camera FOV, what methods (including NLA & scripting) would available in 2.80, ideally without needing to create a separate material for each plane, just to change the starting video frame number?

Comment: Read [Movie Clip On Plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane/39885#39885)

Comment: Read also: [Same Video on each face, but with different time delay?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay/61339#61339)

Comment: Thanks cegaton for such a quick reply and great reference answer ! I have those elements under control. What I’m trying to figure out if I need to create a separate material for each plane or if there’s a way to use scripting to supply a list of offsets and corresponding frame numbers to a script that will make those changes just before and after the plane passes through the FOV. If there’s a similar question, awesome! (My first stackexchange question ever, btw!)

Comment: Wow! I AM TOTALLY adapting that script. Thanks cegaton, you sir are a sharpshooter and an archer!

Comment: There is a lot of information on this site. You can use the search box at the top. Welcome to the site.