# Loop imported video in Blender Model

Tags: import, video, loop

I think this is a bit of a unconventional question, but!

I have a few videos (.mp4) imported into my blender model - I've done this through [Import -> Images as Planes].

I am trying to create an animation, walking through the model - however, my videos start playing as soon as the animation starts, and once they play through, they just stop. So, when the camera reaches them (say at frame 300) in the animation they are just stopped stills showing only the last frame of the video.

Is there a way to loop the videos in Blender? Or make them start at a later point? So that they are either constantly playing, or atleast playing at the right time the camera reaches them?

I am new to blender, so I'm trying to find a simple way to do this, or atleast a method that I can follow - I still don't know most of Blenders nooks and crannies and sadly I'm still trying to get my head around it!! :(

If it's possible to actually do this without having to edit the videos themselves, this would be so so helpful!!

Thank you!

[I am using Blender 2.82a on Mac]

Comment: as for video controls: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane

Comment: maybe you can keyframe the StartFrame / Offset properties at the end of the video? I don't know much about video textures though

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the base colour tab in the properties panel and check on cyclic. That seems to work and the video plays on loop. Hope that helps.