# How to add playing videos to the 3d viewport?

Tags: modeling, python, rendering, mesh, scripting

Is it possible to add videos to the 3d viewport? I want to add multiple ones playing in a loop.

Comment: You can add them in a plane, the same way you add an image or you could use image as plane add on included in blender (go to Edit > preferences > Addons and search for that

Comment: Create a plane, give it a material, in the Shader Editor create an Image Texture node, plug it into a Diffuse that you plug into the Material Output, in the Image Texture load your video, tweak some of its settings

Comment: @moonboots Which part of the node do I connect to which part? I did it but it just shows a still image of the first frame

Comment: In the Image Texture node, in Frames, choose the amount of frames of your movie. Also plug a Texture Coordinate (Generated output) in the Vector socket of the Image Texture

Comment: See: [Movie Clip On Plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane)

Comment: Is the question about displaying an image in the background while modeling or to create elements that will be composited over the video? Or is the question about creating planes with video as a texture? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Create a plane, give it a material.

In the *Shader Editor* create this node chain: *Texture Coordinate* (*Generated* output socket) > *Image Texture* > *Diffuse* or *Emission* > *Material Output*. You may also want to put a *Mapping* node between the *Texture Coordinate* and the *Image Texture* in order to move the movie in the plane.

In the *Image Texture* load your video, tweak some of its settings: enable *Auto-Refresh* and set the amount of frames your movie requires.

[image]

Or, as No-Can-Do says, enable the *Import Images As Planes* addon and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Images > Images As Planes*
and open the *Shader Editor* to tweak the settings.

If your video is not a video file, but a series of numbered images. Press the gear icon when adding an image as plane, and select Animate Image Sequences,so that all the images are imported in a single plane and not as multiple planes, each one with a single frame.

[image]

Comment: Or use the add images as planes add-on. It will let you import an image sequence. To play in a loop enable  cyclic

Comment: oh you're right, I'm going to edit