# How do I add a picture to an 2D animation video

Tags: animation, 2d

So I am making a video and I want to add a photo to make it look funnier, I know that it works on the General selection (the 3D one) but is it possible to put it in a 2D animation way, just like they do in Adobe Animate, or at least in the video editing section?

For example, at the beginning of [his video](https://youtu.be/mgkKG2oGCgE) he used two photos to make his eyes blink. Or how he used the UPS and Jimmy Johns logo, too. So my big question is, is that even possible, and if yes how?

2D animation with the picture of the eyes:
[image: image of eyes]

Picture of the logo:
[image: logo picture embedded in 2d animation]

Link to the [example video](https://youtu.be/mgkKG2oGCgE).

Comment: Hi Pickme. Please be aware of that we try to help you but you have to do something for this. 2 sentences and a video link is...not enough. At least you should insert the timestamp of the video where the animation is - or better add a screenshot in here. So if you don't want that the question will be closed quickly because it needs more detail you should invest some time to write a better question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you see the video how he added the pictures can you even do that?

Comment: yes, i saw the video. But because the question is closed (which - in my eyes is correct because of lack of quality and information of your question) i cannot answer. And yes, of course this is possible with blender.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the *2D Animation* workspace switch to *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>).

In the *Object* mode you can import a picture as plane:

- enabled the *Import-Export: Images as Planes* add-on
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, select *Image > Images As Planes*. (See [Movie Clip On Plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane) for details.)
- if you have a picture with more than one logo, duplicate the plane for backup, switch to *Edit* mode, and use the knife tool (<kbd>k</kbd>) to cut the area you need.

The logo's visibility can be controlled by keyframes. Just keyframe the *Object Data Properties > Visibility > Show In > [X] Viewports* and *... > Show In > [X] Renders* to show and hide it when you want.

In the same way, it is possible to add 3D objects (*File > Append ...*).

[image: grease pencil scene]

To return to *Draw* mode don't forget to select the greasy pencil object ("*Strokes*") in the outliner, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>8</kbd> will work.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: well the picture did come up but when I did the visibility part it just kept showing

Comment: Have you changed the current frame? Select frame 1, hide object + insert keyframe, then select frame 10, and turn on visibility + insert a keyframe. Select frame 20 and hide it again + insert a keyframe. The *2D Animation* has *Auto Keying* enabled by default & you might not need to insert a keyframe explicitly. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/SZJswvw9wEs If you can't see the keyframes in the timeline because the object is hidden change the editor from *Timeline* to *Dope Sheet* & enable *Show Hidden* (it's the button at the bottom of the picture at the right side, next to "Nearest Frame")

Comment: Ok got it thank you so much again